# Can "something I see" mean "I see something"?

Tags: word-order, lyrics

In ABBA's [*I have a dream*](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/abba/ihaveadream.html) song there's a part like

> I believe in angels
>   Something good in everything I see

When I first read it I though it means something like

> I believe in angels [which are] something good in everything [what] I see

But now it occurred to me that it could in fact be something like the following, but expressed in Yoda style:

> I believe in angels. I see something good in everything.

For a native<sup>†</sup> English speaker, is the latter version consistent with the original lyrics?

<sub><sub><sup>†</sup>I know that ABBA are not native English speakers</sub></sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Songs very often take liberties with language. Sometimes the liberties are with word order. But here, I think the liberties are omitted words, and the full sentence would be

> There is something good in everything I see.

This is roughly equivalent to “I see something good in everything”, but not exactly. “I see something good in everything” allows for the speaker to see something good where there is nothing good. “There is something good in everything I see” claims that everything that the speaker can see *does* in fact contain something good; it's a stronger claim.